# UK shares Investment advice

Tags: united-kingdom, shares, isa

Having read the Motley Fool UK Investment guide many years ago, I have invested in various index trackers through ISA over the years and am very happy with this.

However... I just read the (US) Motley Fool Investment Guide 2017 and I am tempted to try investing in shares I chose myself (kind of) following their advice, to try and "beat the index".
I understand it will take a bit of "home work".

I looked at fool.co.uk and got immediately attacked by their hard sale of services... to my great disappointment as I was looking for forums (which used to be great).
So I am not so sure anymore that they are really "helping" me...

I am tempted to open a new Share ISA this year and try but a wondering where to find "impartial" advice...

Any idea where to find this if I can't trust the motley fool? Or should I trust the motley fool and pay their £150/year advice fee? (of course I am extremely lucky and could get 50% discount...)

Thanks

Eric